# Partial derivatives of this function

Tags: symbolic, differentials

I have a function $y(x)$ which is the solution of the initial value problem -

$y = \frac{1-y}{A} - \frac{y.|r(x)+m(x)|^2}{B}$ with an initial condition $y_0=1$.

I solved for $y(x)$ using the following piece of code -

```
y = DSolveValue[{y'[x] == (1 - y[x])/A - (1/B)*y[x]*abs (r[x] + m[x])^2, y[1] == 1}, y[x], x]
```

and this works well.

I want to calculate the partial derivative of $y$ with $r$.

I somewhat naively tried the following -

```
dydr = D[y[r], {r, m}]
```

which produced the following result (I am unable to copy the result onto the editor) -

[image]

which is the exact same output for $y$ as obtained from the first piece of code and this isn't very useful. As a newbie to Mathematica, I am unable to figure out how to do it correctly or if it is even possible.

Comment: I am okay with the question being downvoted, but please do mention WHY you downvoted it so that I can either edit the question or delete it altogether.

Comment: I did not downvote; however, note that `abs` should be `Abs` and its argument must be in function brackets not parentheses. Since `r` is a function of `x` you cannot use a standalone `r`. Then `dydr = D[y[x], x]/D[r[x], x]` or just `y'[x]/r'[x]`

Comment: So I am a little curious. "abs" is doing something. It doesn't throw an error. So what is the difference between abs and Abs? I don't seem to be able to find any documentation online

Comment: `Abs` is a built-in symbol that is defined in the wolfram language. `abs` is not built-in and has no definition unless you have defined it yourself. This is easily found in the documentation: [`Abs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html).

Comment: Mathematica is case sensitive. All internal names start with a capital letter. [`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html) is a built-in function. `abs` was interpreted as a user-defined variable. Since no assignment was made to `abs` you should have seen its color as blue; whereas, `Abs` would be black.

Comment: also, note that `abs (expr)` is interpreted as an unknown constant `abs` times whatever's in the parentheses (`expr`), so it's not expected to throw an error

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of subtle, but easy to make mistakes here.

First, you probably meant `Abs` not `abs`, but if your variables are real this can be omitted anyway.

Next you reuse the variable `y`.  You are using it on the RHS but defining it on the left.  If you evaluate this more than once you will get confused.  So, I use `yy` on the LHS.

You evaluate a value for `y[x]` then try to use it as a pure function.  (This is a subtle point, but note that I have `...,y, x]` where you had `...,y[x],x]`.)

So now you can evaluate

```
yy = DSolveValue[{y'[x] == (1 - y[x])/A - (1/B)*y[x] (r[x] + m[x])^2, 
   y[1] == 1}, y, x]
(* Function[{x},  ... body omitted ...] *)
```

I'm a bit confused by your attempt to take a partial derivative.  You are using `r` and `m` as functions, but you are then evaluating your function `yy` at `r`.

```
D[yy[R], R]
```

appears to work.

Note that the syntax you use `D[y[r],{r,m}]` means take the `m`th derivative wrt `r`.  (I guess you really intended to use a mixed derivative `D[y[r],r,m]`.

Hope that this gets you started, anyway.